# Remover a sombra o TabLayout API 21

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu quero remove a sombra do `TabLayout`, mas na API 21 nada está funcionando.

Eu tentei definir `windowContentOverlay` ou o `elevation` para `null` e nada funciona.

A tela renderizada fica assim:

[image: Tabs layout shadow]

E meu código está assim:

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        style="@style/tabs"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Faça isso no onCreate da Activity

```
TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabs.setElevation(0);
```